# Box shadow based on z-index like Material Design

Tags: css, z-index, material-design, shadow

I've been looking at Material Design for a while and I wanted to recreate sheets of material merging together as seen in [this video](https://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_4/material_ext_publish/0B6Okdz75tqQsRmdDaEl6aTVGREU/whatismaterial-materialprop-transformingmaterial-PaperHeal_xhdpi_004.webm).

It looks simple but I just couldn't get the shadows to be working.
Lets say each of the sheets has a z-index of 1. You would think the box-shadow of each element would fall behind the other element (because they are on the same z-index) but they actually stack.

I've tried putting the sheet and 'shadow' element in a container and making the sheet a higher z-index than the shadow but with multiple cards the shadow still appears above the cards.

So my question is: **Is there a way to recreate these sheets merging together with the shadows of both always appearing behind the cards?**

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick if you want the shadow to show on all 4 sides but not overlap, like between div 1 and 2, is to use a pseudo element.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width : 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px #666;
  text-align: center;
}
div:nth-child(3) {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

div:after {
    content: "";
    left: 2px;
    right: 2px;
    height: 10px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    box-shadow: 0px -1px 3px #aaa;
}
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
```

Comment: That sure is what I was looking for! I now see the reason why it was not working with what I had. In this [codepen](http://codepen.io/cvaneenige/pen/XXxYpR) I've used your code with my shadow.. This way it still appears to be above the second card..

Comment: @Colin Usually one make the shadow go above the element, which cause this oddity. In your movie link they don't.

Comment: In the movie there is a small shadow on top. It is actually the same shadow in my codepen but the top shadow from the second sheet still appears to be above the first one.. It is really weird.

Comment: Your snippet right now is the solution I was looking for! I updated my [codepen](http://codepen.io/cvaneenige/pen/XXxYpR) and it works! I've actually tried using the pseudo element but there was one thing I didn't try.. the negative z-index! It only seems to work with a negative z-index! Even when the cards are 2 and the shadow is 1 it wont work! With a negative value it does. Thank you for helping me out!